# How to inform a service, that an activity has finished

Tags: android, service, android-activity, activity-finish

I have a service, that starts an activity like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

How to inform the service, that MyActivity has finished?

Any hints appreciated,
Marcus

Comment: an activity can never be started using startActivity from a Service which runs in Background

Comment: Can't see any valid reason for the down vote so cancelling it out to restore the natural balance of the AndroidVerse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in OnDestroy method of the activity, either you can invoke a method of the service, if you have service class object, if you don't have, Use Broadcast Receiver, to send some message, to Service, and in Service implement that Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: invoking sounds great. just how do I get the service in the activity?

Comment: If you have Binded Server, with some Binder, then you have Service Reference, in your class, but from your problem, it seems you dont have Service reference, so second option is only available to you.

Comment: I'm writing the service, too. so, you're suggesting to use bindService?

Comment: binding seems to be problematic on rotationchagnes etc from what I'm reading. ok, will look into the broadcast receiver. thnx 8)